# Get SQL statement after parameters added

Tags: sql, mysql, parameters

Is there a way (in MySQL) to get the pure SQL statement after parameters have been added? I'm having issues with one of my statements once I start using parameters, and I want to see what's being executed. Of course it has to do with dates.

Using MySQL .NET Connector. I have access to MySQL server, and I use SQLYog to administrate.

Thanks!
-Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query logs option to have all queries issued to the server logged.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html for information about the log types and how to enable and configure them.