# How can I obtain the string representation of a SqlParameter, without submitting a SQL statement to the server?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, parameters, tostring

How can I convert a parameterized string such as "(@param1, @param2, @param3)" to a normal SQL statement (like if I were to execute the query)?

This would be helpful to directly replace a set of parameters by their values in a batch (very long) insert query, where the same parameter names could be reused.

I am aware of the following questions, but they do not provide a proper answer (except asserting that it is the server which does the conversions from the parameters it has received separately):

- [How to get the SQL actually executed by a parameterized query in .Net (VB or C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503332/how-to-get-the-sql-actually-executed-by-a-parameterized-query-in-net-vb-or-c)
- [Get SQL statement after parameters added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408169/get-sql-statement-after-parameters-added)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for,  but I created an extension method for `SqlCommand` called `ToSql()` that declares all Parameters, sets literal values,  and then uses the CommandText to generate a stand-alone SQL statement.  I can then copy and paste the statement into SSMS and continue debugging from there.

I wish I could share the code with you, but it's the property of my employer. Besides,  it was actually pretty easy to write, and is a fun exercise. I'll just describe how it works.

For example:

```
var command = new SqlCommand(@"
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table 
    WHERE 
        Column1 = @Param1 
    AND Column2 = @Param2
");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", 555);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", "StackOverflow's cool");
...
```

Now, while debugging, I simply add a watch for `command.ToSQL()`, and I get the following text:

```
DECLARE @Param1   INT            SET @Param1   = 555
DECLARE @Param2   VARCHAR(MAX)   SET @Param2   = 'StackOverflow''s cool'
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE
    Column1 = @Param1
AND Column2 = @Param2
```

For stored procedures, the result looks like this:

```
DECLARE @Param1   INT            SET @Param1   = 555
DECLARE @Param2   VARCHAR(MAX)   SET @Param2   = 'StackOverflow''s cool'
EXECUTE Some_Stored_Procedure
    @Param1 = @Param1
   ,@Param2 = @Param2
```

I wouldn't recommend using this code in production, and it might not be safe against SQL injection attacks,  but it's an incredibly useful debugging tool!

Comment: Ideally, it should be possible to benefit from the same protection from SQL injection attacks.
Are you simply using a switch statement on DbType to convert into literal values as accepted by your destination database (which unfortunately would not be database neutral)?

Comment: Yeah, I escape all strings, but I'm not sure if that provides complete security.  Since my extension method uses `SqlCommand`, I switch on `SqlDbType`, and either surround with `'` (for varchar, uniqueidentifier, etc) or output the literal value (for int, decimal, etc).  It gets the job done, but by no means is it "production-ready" ... it's just a quick little debugging tool I threw together.

Comment: I suppose you could abstract the code away from `SqlCommand`, and make it work for `DbCommand`, but each supported database would probably need its own configuration (for determining literal values, escaping strings, etc).  That sounds like a fun afternoon for someone.  ... Not it!

Answer (score 0):

I've just found something like that for SQLite:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO `" + rolesTable + "`" +
                " (Rolename, ApplicationName) " +
                " Values($Rolename, $ApplicationName)", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("$Rolename", DbType.String, 255).Value = rolename;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("$ApplicationName", DbType.String, 255).Value = ApplicationName;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand how it answers my question... I need to convert the cmd.CommandText to a "standalone" query that I could execute directly on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I've misread your question. As parameters are send with query I would probably iterate through parameters and replace query string  with `switch(parameter.DbType)` and format it as I desire. I know it's a long way. But if it's only for your logs...